# How to tell which control a contextmenustip is associated with?

Tags: c#

I have two labels one lblEmail1 and two lblEmal2 each has the same context menu strip associated with it. The contextmenustip has one menu item which is "Send Email" when I right click on either label and you select "Send Email" it goes to the same function to process the request which would be to take the value lblEmail1.Text or lblEmail2.Text and start an email. The problem is I can't figure out how to tell which label initiated the request. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

add an event handler for the menu's opened event
Sender will be which of the labels triggered it.
Store that somewhere, the email menuitem's tag property would be good, or a private variable on the form class.

Then in the Onclick of the menu item test and proceed accordingly.